# Google Drive API. Get Shared link (sharedUrl)

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Can I somehow get **sharedLink** without displaying `gapi.drive.share.ShareClient()` dialog? I just want to make my own Picker dialog to share files.

I've investigated that this dialog connects to external url `/sharing/commonshare/`
to set shared state and get sharedLinks.

[image]
[image]

As you see there is "token" prop in POST request. (First picture)
To get it API does another request

[image]
I have all data to GET it. But I get 405 Error.

Actually I don't want to try that hard. 
Does documentation about it exist? Because I didn't find anything like that.

> I just want to share selected file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only get the status `"shared": true` if you've already shared the drive file before. So if you want get that status just share the file to someone and perform a [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) request. But, I think what you're really after is to get the shareable link. This shareable link used to be `alternateLink` in Drive V2 but is now [webViewLink in V3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration).

So to get `webViewLink` (shareable link), perform a `files.get` and you'll have something that looks like:

```
"webViewLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/abcdefghijklmnopFbVRzT0pkTkk/view?usp=drivesdk"
```

Note however that this shareable link is viewable only to those who have [permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create). Use permissions.create to add them. Set `'type'` to `'anyone'` to share file to everyone.

Also you need to set `'withLink'` to `true` as described in API v2.
Or `'allowFileDiscovery': false` in API v3. 
So your permissions won't change but file would be shareable by a link.

Comment: Yes. You are right. But as far as I understand.
Making file shareable by a link doesn't change it's permissions (through google drive UI for example) or by `gapi.drive.share.ShareClient()`.
When I set shareable by a link in GD UI. And then get file's permission. It's ("role": "owner", "type": "user"). So the question is "How to set file's state to shareable by a link" without changing permissions.